# Sequalize save array of items

Tags: database, orm, sequelize.js, nestjs, many-to-many

I have many to many relations between the two tables `actors` and `movies` I try to execute this code but sequalize don't save `actors`

```
  const arr = [];

    actors.forEach((element:string) => {
      const x = this.actorsService.createActor(element);
      arr.push(x);
    });
    await Promise.all(arr);


    const movie = await this.moviesRepository.create({
      ...dto,
      actors: arr,
    });
```

Firstly, I get an array of strings (actors); for each element, I create a new actor inside createActor. Later I want to put that data into a movie but anything I don't save

Comment: could you share the schema of Actor and Movies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arr` still stores promises and not the actor instances. You need to store the result of `Promise.all` to get actor instances:

```js
const arr = await Promise.all(actors.map(x => this.actorsService.createActor(x)));

const movie = await this.moviesRepository.create({
  ...dto,
  actors: arr,
});
```